# Android BroadcastReceiver does'nt work when screen is turned off

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, android-broadcast

I have a BroadcastReceiver with ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED. I get events only when the screen is turned on.

I want to get events of battery change even if the screen is turned off? How?

Answer (score 0):

If you put your receiver in the manifest, It should be alive all the time.

Comment: No.  Look at the docs for ACTION_BATTERY_*.  You are not allowed to register them in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it is generally not great form to ask the same question multiple times.  I answered this question, for you, here:

[Android keep BroadcastReceiver while the app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22283851/android-keep-broadcastreceiver-while-the-app-is-closed/22284444#22284444)

Comment: But this don't work when I turn off the screen. Only when the app opened/closed (screen on).